# How to query to get this result?

Tags: sql

3 tables are there,one is student,second one is subject and third one is marks table.

```
student table:
    student_id  student_name

subject table:
    subject_id  subject_name

marks table:
    student_id   subject_id  marks
```

I written this query:

```
select student_id, subject_id, marks, RANK() over (partition by subject_id order by marks desc rank 
from marks order by student_id, subject_id;
```

it's giving proper results but I want student_name and subject_name in place of student_id and subject_id.

How to join these tables?
Thanks.

Comment: You're writing a query that uses `Rank Over Partition` but you don't understand a simple `Join` concept...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a couple of `join` clauses:

```
SELECT   student_name, subject_name, marks, 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY subject_name ORDER BY marks DESC) rk
FROM     marks
JOIN     student ON marks.student_id = student.student_id
JOIN     subject ON marks.subject_id = subject.subject_id
ORDER BY student_name, subject_name
```

Comment: Sorry, Rows are not updated propery thats why given only 2 rows.Now its giving results properly

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simple join

```
    select student_name,  subject_name, marks, RANK() over (partition by subject_id order by marks desc) rank 
     from marks 
     inner join student on mark.student_id=student.student_id
     inner join subject on mark.subject_id=subject.subject_id
     order by student_id, subject_id;
```